# Node.js nested callbacks using request-promise not working

Tags: node.js, promise, callback

I have a very simple nodejs/express API that is making a `request.get()` inside `request.post()`. I simply want to res.send the response body of `request.get()`.

I've tried using a simple callback function with `request` and `request-promise... .then()` method to no avail.

```
const request = require('request')
const rp = require('request-promise')

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    var mapCenter
    var address = "user query"

    res.send(submitSearch());

    function submitSearch() {
        if (!mapCenter || !mapCenter.lat) {
            googleMapsClient.geocode({
                address: address,
            }, function(err, res) {
                if (!err) {
                    mapCenter = {lat:res.lat, lng:res.lng };

                    submitSearch();
                }
            });
        } else {
            var parameters = {
                uri: domain,
                form: {
                    latitude: mapCenter.lat,
                    longitude: mapCenter.
                },
                json: true
            }
            rp.post(parameters).then(function(res) {
                return getResults(res.id)
             })
        }
    }

    function getResults(id) {
        rp.get(domain+ id).then(function(res) {
            return res.Results;
         })

    }
})
```

In the `app.get()` function, I expect my `res.send(submitSearch())` to spit out my `return getResults(res.id)` statement in my `rp.post()` call which should finally give `return res.Results` in my `getResults()` function.

The most befuddling part of this is that I need that weird  if statement in `submitSearch()` for `googleMapsClient` to properly assign `mapCenter` and then recursively call `submitSearch()` again. I understand that this is an async issue and the countless threads and videos I've watch do not cover this particular type of case.

Comment: Uhh, do NOT edit your question to include your final solution.  That's not how things work here at stackoverflow.  Questions remain as questions.  Answers are where the answers are.  We want your question to show the original question you asked so this can be a lasting reference of the original question and then one or more answers to that question.  Please edit your question to put it back the way it was.

Comment: Noted. Although @Akatsuki levi's answer did not give me the correct results. His insight led me edit the code myself to get what I needed. Is it ok if I accept his/her answer still?

Comment: You can add your own answer to show what you eventually decided to use (yes, you can answer your own questions).  I'm working on an answer that I think is better than both if you want to wait a bit because it's really a lot simpler to use the promise interface to googleMaps and to chain promise so you can have all your error handling in one place.  Levi's answer is missing a LOT of error handling.

Comment: I posted my simplified answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the promise API for `.geocode()` and then you aren't trying to mix plain callbacks and promises.  Not only will this streamline your code, but it will also make robust error handling a lot simpler.  All the proposals I've seen here so far are missing all sorts of error handling.  I also don't see any reason why you need to recursively call yourself here.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    let address = "user query";

    // use promise interface for geocode
    googleMapsClient.geocode({address}).asPromise().then(response => {
        return {lat: response.lat, lng: response.lng };
    }).then(mapCenter => {
        const parameters = {
            uri: domain,
            form: {
                latitude: mapCenter.lat,
                longitude: mapCenter.lng
            },
            json: true
        };
        return rp.post(parameters);        
    }).then(id => {
        return rp.get(domain+ id).then(res => res.Results);
    }).then(results => {
        res.send(results);
    }).catch(err => {
        // decide what to do here if there's an error
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

Note, the [Google doc on using promises](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js#quick-start) shows this:

```
const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
  key: 'your API key here',
  Promise: Promise
});
```

So, it might be that you need to tell it which Promise implementation to use when you initialize things like this to use the built-in Promise.

Comment: Thank you very much @jfriend00. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the StackOverflow!
And, as i saw on your code, your calling the res.send before you set the function.
And the submitSearch is calling itself?
For ease i'd rewrite the code like this:

```js
const request = require('request')
const rp = require('request-promise')

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    var mapCenter;
    var address = "user query";

    if (!mapCenter || !mapCenter.lat) {
        googleMapsClient.geocode({
            address: address,
        }, function(err, geocodeResponse) {
            if (!err) {
                mapCenter = {lat:res.lat, lng:res.lng };
                res.send(geocodeResponse);
            } else {
                throw err; // throw the error if isn't a assert.
            }
        });
    } else {
        var parameters = {
            uri: domain,
            form: {
                latitude: mapCenter.lat,
                longitude: mapCenter.lng
            },
            json: true
        };
        rp.post(parameters).then(function() {
            rp.get(domain+ id).then(function(reqPromiseRes) {
                res.send(geocodeResponse);
            })
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: I see that you're res.sending `geoCodeResponse` which is from `googleMapsClient`. I'm actually calling `submitSearch` again because I need to `res.send` the `post body` from the else statement. Specifically I am posting to a custom domain _after_ setting `mapCenter` with `googleMapsClient`.